# Convert rows to columns with group in mysql java swing

Tags: java, mysql, pivot

I am developing a java swing applivcation. I am having a table as follows:

```
Date        Name    Amount
20-1-2014   John    100
20-1-2014   John    50
20-1-2014   James   270
20-1-2014   James   40
20-1-2014   Thomas  70
20-1-2014   Thomas  80
21-1-2014   John    20
21-1-2014   John    40
21-1-2014   James   45
21-1-2014   James   85
21-1-2014   Thomas  10
21-1-2014   Thomas  90
```

I need the result as follows with dynamic column names

```
Date       John  James  Thomas
20-1-2014   150  310    150
21-1-2014   60   130    100
```

I had searched the internet but there is no suitable answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the *pivot* table operator. Unfortunately Mysql doesn't have a native `pivot` operator like SQL Server and other RDBMS, but you can do it like this:

```
SELECT
  Date,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'John' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'John', 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'James' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'James', 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Name = 'Thomas' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'Thomas',
  SUM(Amount) AS Total
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Date;
```

---

**Update:**

If you want to do this dynamically for any names, instead of writing them manually, you have to do that with dynamic sql. Something like this:

```
SET @cols = NULL;
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(Name = ''',
      Name, ''', Amount , NULL)) AS ', '''', Name , '''')
  ) INTO @cols
FROM table1;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT 
  Date, ', @cols , ', SUM(Amount) AS Total 
FROM table1
GROUP BY Date;');

prepare stmt 
FROM @sql;

execute stmt;
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/bcbee5/3)

You can put that query inside a stored procedure and call it.

Comment: ,I want to show the column names dynamically

Comment: @user2601972 - OK, I will edit my answer for the dynamic version.

Comment: ,Please let me know how to call this from java swing code with from date and to date selection

Comment: @user2601972 - I don't know how to call that from java, you can start a new question in that subject or search for how to call stored procedure from java swing.

Comment: ,how to get addition of columns at the last column

Comment: @user2601972 - What do you mean? All the names which will be the columns headers are populated dynamically, the query will firstly get all the distinct names from the table comma separated in the parameter `@cols`. Do you mean add a new name as a column header, or other grouped column like date???

Comment: ,like john+james+Thomas=Total

Comment: @user2601972 - You can add `SUM(Amount) AS Total` at the end of the columns, like in my edit.

Comment: how to get sum of column values at the bottom

Comment: @user2601972 - This is a different question, try to search about it or start a new question: https://www.google.com.eg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=glFVU-ClAYmq8QPSnoGAAw#q=sql+server+grouping+and+rollup